# Live Agent custom window with Agent Profile image

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, liveagent

I have used the instructions found here

https://systemdebug.wordpress.com/2015/05/17/live-agent-rest-api-connectapi/

to add the agents image to a custom chat window.

I seem to have some permission issues.

In the Chrome Console I get this error. (The returned Data Array is my GUID, so at least that is working!)

[image: Error Message]

I have checked all the permissions for the user profile that is assigned to my Visual Force Site. I have ensured it has rights to access the Apex Class and the Visualforce Page.

What have I missed?

Comment: Apologies  for not replying to you on the blog. I have been busy, when I tested this I may have done it as an authenticated user. I think this is related to this https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000keDRAAY 

Let me see if I can get this to work as a  guest user.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the update, let me know how your testing goes